# Does SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE also return points inside a polygon?

Tags: oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

Using Oracle Spatial Database, just wondering if the SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE returns points inside a polygon, not just within a certain number of metres from the boundary.

I've already checked the documentation, it trivially states:

> Uses the spatial index to identify the set of spatial objects that are
>   within some specified distance of a given object, such as an area of
>   interest or point of interest.

I would have thought that it should as being inside a polygon would count as being a distance of 0m from a polygon...

Comment: What happens if you run a test on some known data?  The SQL and result of that would be a useful addition to your question.

Comment: So this is for a client and I'm off-site. Trying to do background research before I head in. It would in fact answer my question if I had the data. I was hoping someone could clarify given the documentation is so lack-lustre.

Comment: Can't you just dummy up a few points and a simple polygon like a square to test on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. It also returns object that **touch** or **overlap** the polygon. This is because two objects that interact in any way are at a distance 0 from each other.

For example:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM sales_regions r, customers c
 WHERE r.region_id = 'R1'
   AND sdo_within_distance (
         c.location, r.geom,
         'distance=10 unit=km') 
       = 'TRUE';
```

will count all points that are within a virtual buffer of 10km around the polygon **and** also those points that are inside the polygon.

To only retain those that are outside the polygon, do this:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM sales_regions r, customers c
 WHERE r.region_id = 'R1'
   AND sdo_within_distance (
         c.location, r.geom,
         'distance=10 unit=km') 
       = 'TRUE‘
   AND sdo_geom.sdo_distance (
         c.location, r.geom, 0.5) > 0;
```

i.e. only retain the points where the distance to the polygon is > 0.